# Do I need to close connection before response.end?

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic

In classic asp I have the file **open.asp** and **close.asp** included at top and bottom of every page. Somewhere I have **response.end** in my codes. Do I need to close connection before response.end or the server translates the page to the end of page after response.end?

Content of open.asp:

```
Set objcon = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objcon.connectionString="DSN=something"
objcon.Open
```

content of close.asp:

```
objcon.close
set objcon=nothing
```

Please note that I have no problem with multiple connections and memory leak. My exact question is about behavior of of server against "Response.End"

Comment: Yes. You do. otherwise you might end up with a memory leak.

Comment: Well, before calling the Response.End you can call Server.Execute("close.asp")

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connection leaks in Classic ASP using Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7896241/connection-leaks-in-classic-asp-using-server-createobjectadodb-connection)

Comment: Another possible duplicate of [Properly closing a database connection - VBScript + MS SQL](//stackoverflow.com/q/12536414)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Properly closing a database connection - VBScript + MS SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536414/properly-closing-a-database-connection-vbscript-ms-sql)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Response.End stops further execution of the page. From the [docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524629(v=vs.90).aspx): "The remaining contents of the file are not processed." So, no, the connection object won't get cleaned up in this scenario.

It's better to go ahead and create connection objects at a more granular level and destroy/release them as soon as possible back to the ADO connection pool, which is what manages the actual connections to the database. Reusing a connection object leaves it more vulnerable to not getting cleaned up properly.